# type input list for launch method in ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add file from the internal storage.

my code

```
resultLauncher = 
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri : 
Uri? ->
        ....

    }
```

in the launcher I want to get just doc files.
I saw in tutorials that I can do it for images like:

```
getContent.launch("image/*")
```

can't find string for docs and every other types.
I'll glad for strings list.
and also links for relevant info

thanks

Comment: `launch()` takes MIME types. [Here is a list of popular MIME types](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/).

Comment: thanks. I'm searching for docx and there isn't there or at least for all kind of doc files. there is a way to add more then one type?

Comment: "I'm searching for docx and there isn't there or at least for all kind of doc files" -- a search on DuckDuckGo for `docx mime type` turned up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc#4212908. "there is a way to add more then one type?" -- if you switch to `OpenDocument` from `GetContent`, I think `launch()` takes a `vararg` of strings, so you can provide 1, 2, many, or lots of MIME types.